# PsychoPy builder view key press- storing correct and incorrect answers

Tags: python, psychopy

I am using builder view in PsychoPy 2. I have different loops of trials that come from an external excel file.

For each trial there is either and X or a Z stimuli. For the X, participants are meant to press 'a', for Z they press 'l'. the trial changes after one key press,so the participant either gets it right or wrong and then moves on. 
Right now only the key the participant presses is being recorded. What I would like to be recorded is the key the participant pressed as well as if they were right or wrong. I am meant to be recording their reaction time and accuracy, so it is hard to track their accuracy if I only know what button they pressed and not if it was right or wrong.

This is my very first project so I am not good at code, a response for builder view would be preferable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Post whatever relevant code you have within the body of your question (*we are not a code writing service*). We should be able to paste your code into a text file. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: [what kinds of questions can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and remember to **[include Minimal, complete, Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Then `edit` your question, so that we may help.

Answer (score 0):

In the keyboard component, tick the "Store correct" check box. This opens a up a new field, where you type the name of the variable in your conditions file that specifies the correct answer.

*StackOverflow is really for programming questions. For the Builder GUI of PsychoPy, you will probably be better served going to the forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org*